# How do I set cache control to css and js files in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, cache-control

I'm new to SpringBoot.

I make my project based on a [sample project of Springboot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/). I'd like to control the http headers for cache just for js/css files.

I've added a js file `test.js` under `src/resources/static` then reference it in `greeting.html`.

Then I follow some answers on StackOverflow and add the `WebMvcConfiguration.java` and `WebSecurityConfig.java` as such but it doesn't work for me.

I'm sure whether WebMvcConfiguration and WebSecurityConfig should not be used together or I've configured something wrong. I prefer a solution with Java Config, not XML.

I open ChromeDevTool to check the response from server. The reponse http header is

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-store
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Thu, 02 Feb 2017 10:53:14 GMT
Expires:
Last-Modified:Thu, 02 Feb 2017 10:52:49 GMT
Pragma:
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:
When I removed `WebSecurityConfig`, I got the following header

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:no-store
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Thu, 02 Feb 2017 11:14:51 GMT
Last-Modified:Thu, 02 Feb 2017 11:14:20 GMT
```

**greeting.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script th:src="@{/test.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

**WebMvcConfiguration.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/test.js").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.csrf().disable()
              .headers()
              .defaultsDisabled()
              .cacheControl();
  }
}
```

Comment: @dur, I'd like to set 31556926. I don't know what set no caching in Spring Security. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @dur, I have removed WebSecurityConfig and WebMvcConfiguration. I got `no store` in the reponse http header for `test.js`

Comment: No, there is no other filter. The same for .css

Answer (score 5):

Modern SpringBoot (at least in 2018, not sure when it got added), has properties for managing this:

```
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.cache-private= # Indicate that the response message is intended for a single user and must not be stored by a shared cache.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.cache-public= # Indicate that any cache may store the response.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age= # Maximum time the response should be cached, in seconds if no duration suffix is not specified.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.must-revalidate= # Indicate that once it has become stale, a cache must not use the response without re-validating it with the server.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-cache= # Indicate that the cached response can be reused only if re-validated with the server.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-store= # Indicate to not cache the response in any case.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.no-transform= # Indicate intermediaries (caches and others) that they should not transform the response content.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.proxy-revalidate= # Same meaning as the "must-revalidate" directive, except that it does not apply to private caches.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.s-max-age= # Maximum time the response should be cached by shared caches, in seconds if no duration suffix is not specified.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.stale-if-error= # Maximum time the response may be used when errors are encountered, in seconds if no duration suffix is not specified.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.stale-while-revalidate= # Maximum time the response can be served after it becomes stale, in seconds if no duration suffix is not specified.
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: In case anyone comes across this question, `max-age` needs to be a duration string so for 7 days: `spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age: 7d`

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to springboot. I just added the following to my application.properties file.

```
spring.resources.chain.cache= false
```

It solved my problem until I figure out more advanced cache controlling.